# Pattern matching on products in Idris

Tags: pattern-matching, idris

Define

```
ZZ : Type
ZZ = (Nat, Nat)
```

Then The following code

```
ZZ_greater_than_zero : ZZ -> Bool
ZZ_greater_than_zero (Z, Z) = False
ZZ_greater_than_zero (Z, (S n)) = False
ZZ_greater_than_zero ((S m), Z) = True
ZZ_greater_than_zero ((S m), (S n)) = ZZ_greater_than_zero (m, n)
```

Gives me

```
10 | ZZ_greater_than_zero (Z, Z) = False
   | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ZZ_ord.ZZ_greater_than_zero is possibly not total due to recursive path ZZ_ord.ZZ_greater_than_zero --> ZZ_ord.ZZ_greater_than_zero
```

But if I define the same function

```
ZZ_greater_than_zero_alt : Nat -> Nat -> Bool
```

Using similar pattern matching it doesn't give the error. There is a possible fix to this problem by defining

```
ZZ_greater_than_zero : ZZ -> Bool
ZZ_greater_than_zero (a, b) = ZZ_greater_than_zero_alt a b
```

But is there a more direct way?

Comment: perhaps doesn't answer your general qu, but isn't this just `m > n`?

Comment: Yes, but I am not interested in this function in particular but on how idris pattern matches on definitions of these kind.

Answer (score 0):

In https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/docs/faq/faq.rst#i-have-an-obviously-terminating-program-but-idris-says-it-possibly-isnt-total-why-is-that the FAQ explicitly mentions that idris does not consider (m,n) to be syntactically smaller than (S m, S n) and proposes to use `assert_total` as a way out.

There is also a type which can be used to prove that some other type is converging against a base case but I can't remember the name of it currently.

Comment: I think you are talking about the accessible type.